# What is the most "elegant" way to implement a class with both CPU and GPU parallelizations in Numba?

Tags: python, design-patterns, numba

Let's just assume that I have implemented two different versions of the same class with Numba:

```py
class cpu_foo(object):
    def init(self, data):
        # initialize the class...

    def compute(self, parameters):
        call_to_parallel_cpu_function(parameters)

class gpu_foo(object):
    def init(self, data):
        # initialize the class...
        # ...with some fine tunings for the gpu computation

    def compute(self, parameters):
        call_to_parallel_cuda_function(parameters)
```

And then, depending on the machine I'm working on, I call either one version or another.

I know that it's an horrible practice to have 2 separate versions of the same code, but I'm unsure on what would be the most "standard" way to implement a class capable of:

- detect if there is a CUDA capable device
- if yes, initialize as a gpu class
- if not, initialize as a cpu class

In general, I was unable to find any design indication for any language about this topic... am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question was more related to design.
A possible design could be:

```
class Gen(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def compute(self, parameters):
        # call_to_parallel_cpu_function(parameters)
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def generate_instance(_data):
        # code to detect if there is a cuda capable device
        # and return true/false and store it in cuda_device variable
        cuda_device = True 
        if cuda_device:
            return GpuFoo(_data)
        else:
            return CpuFoo(_data)


class CpuFoo(Gen):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(CpuFoo, self).__init__()
        self.data = data

    def compute(self, parameters):
        # call_to_parallel_cpu_function(parameters)
        pass


class GpuFoo(Gen):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(GpuFoo, self).__init__()
        self.data = data

    def compute(self, parameters):
        # call_to_parallel_cuda_function(parameters)
        pass

Gen.generate_instance([1]).compute([2])  # an example of how to use
```

`Gen` is a base class which has a static method `generate_instance` which generated the required instance according to the capability of the device. `CpuFoo` and `GpuFoo` are two sub-classes and inherits base class `Gen` and give their own implementation of `compute` method.

Let me know if it helps!!

P.S.. `Gen.generate_instance([1])` detects if device is CUDA capable device and if it's ture, return an instance of `GpuFoo` class else returns an instance of `CpuFoo`.

Comment: Yes, it's a design question in the end (and I have no clue where to study code design). That seems an interesting way to go! I will try it as soon as I can.

Comment: @CarloEmilioMontanari Sure!! take your time. Let me know if any help or further clarification needed.